# On the Lipschitz parametrizability of polynomials of fixed Mahler measure

Tags: nt.number-theory, geometric-measure-theory, heights

**Background**

For a polynomial $f(x) = a(x-\alpha_1) \cdots (x - \alpha_n) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, its Mahler measure is defined to be
$$M(f) = |a| \prod_{i=1}^n \max\{1, |\alpha_i|\}$$
In [Lemma 1, Masser-Vaaler, "Counting algebraic numbers of large height II"](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2007-359-01/S0002-9947-06-04115-8/S0002-9947-06-04115-8.pdf), it's shown that the set
$$S = \{(z_0, \cdots, z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}: M(z_0 x^n + z_1 x^{n-1} + \cdots + z_n) = 1\}$$
is Lipschitz parametrizable of codimension 1.

**Question**
Suppose I have a non-constant polynomial map $F = (F_0, \cdots, F_n): K \subset \mathbb{C}^{m} \to \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, defined on a compact subset $K$ with nonempty interior. Consider the set
$$F^{-1}(S) = \{\mathbf{w} \in K: M(F_0(\mathbf{w}) x^n + F_1(\mathbf{w}) x^{n-1} + \cdots + F_n(\mathbf{w})) = 1\}$$
Is it true that $F^{-1}(S)$ is also Lipschitz parametrizable of codimension 1? If not, are there general conditions on $F$ that can make it happen?

Thank you!